# Don't pass object by reference in AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` that repeats an unordered list. Each item in that list has a button that calls an AngularJS function to add that item to another list. The problem is that the item that is passed to the function is by reference. Meaning, if I update a property in that function, then the object is updated everywhere in my site.

Example of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/156/

You'll see that the left list is also updated. But I only want to update the object that is passed to the function! So, I only want to see the changed in the 2nd list.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript, everything is passed by value. You are just modifying the object that the reference points at.

You could use `angular.copy` to create a new object with the top level references copied.

I added

```
obj = angular.copy(obj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/157/

Answer (score 0):

Native method (ONLY Objects, subfunctions copied as well)

```
var obj = { a : 1, b : 'str', c : function(){ return true; }};
// Deep
var newObject = Object.create(obj);
```

Brutal method (no functions, not cyclic)

```
// Deep
var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Angular method

```
var newObject = angular.copy(obj);
// or
angular.copy(obj, newObject);
```

Jquery method

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, obj);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
```

Underscore method

```
// Shallow
var newObject = _.clone(obj);
```

lodash method

```
// Deep
var newObject = _.clone(obj, true);
```